# Program to help split and manage 2,000 column excel

Tags: csv, multiple-columns

I am building a web application that will run off of data that is produced for the public by a governmental agency.  The issue is that the csv file that houses the data I need is a 2,000 column beast of a file.  The file is what it is, I need to find the best way to take it and modify it.  I know I need to break this data up into much smaller tables within MySQL, but I'm struggling with the best way to do this.  I need to make this as easy as possible to replicate for next year when the data file is produced again (and every year after).  I've searched for programs to help, and everything I've seen deals with a huge amount of rows, not columns.  Has anyone else dealt with this problem before?  Any ideas?  I've spent the last week color coding columns in excel and moving data to new tabs, but this is time consuming, will be super difficult to replicate and I worry it leaves me open for copy and paste errors. I'm at a complete loss here!

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you use functions in excel to give every column an automatic name "column1", "column2", "column3", etc.

After that import the entire csv file into MySQL.

Decide on which columns you want to group together into separate tables. This is the longest step and no program can help you manage this part.

Query your massive SQL table to get just the columns you want for each group. Export these queries to CSV and then import them as new tables in your database.

At the end, if you want, query all the columns you didn't put into separate groups. Make this a new table in the database and delete the original table to save on storage space.

Does this government csv file get updated and republished in the same format every time? If so you'll need to write a script to do all of the above automatically.